# Multiclass text classification using R

Tags: r, h2o, text-classification, gbm, multiclass-classification

I am working on a multiclass text classification problem. I have build a gradient boosting model for the same.

**About the dataset:**

The dataset has two columns: "Test_name" and  "Description"

There are six labels in the Test_Name column and their corresponding description in the  "Description" column.

## **My approach towards the problem**

## DATA PREPARATION

1. Creat a word vector for description.
2. Build a corpus using the word vector.
3. Pre-processing tasks such as removing number, whitespaces, stopwords and conversion to lower case.
4. Build a document term matrix (dtm).
5. Remove sparse words from the above dtm.
6. The above step leads to a count frequency matrix showing the frequency of each word in its coressponding column.
7. Tranform count frequency matrix to a binary instance matrix, which shows occurences of a word in a document as either 0 or 1, 1 for being present and 0 for absent.
8. Append the label column from the original notes dataset with the transformed dtm. The label column has 6 labels.

## Model Building

Using H2o package, build a gbm model.

## **Results obtained**

Four of the class labels are classified well but the rest two are poorly classified.

below is the output:

```
Extract training frame with `h2o.getFrame("train")`
MSE: (Extract with `h2o.mse`) 0.1197392
RMSE: (Extract with `h2o.rmse`) 0.3460335
Logloss: (Extract with `h2o.logloss`) 0.3245868
Mean Per-Class Error: 0.3791268
Confusion Matrix: Extract with `h2o.confusionMatrix(<model>,train = TRUE)`)

Body Fluid Analysis =   401 / 2,759
Cytology Test       =   182 / 1,087
Diagnostic Imaging  =   117 / 3,907
Doctors Advice      =      32 / 752
Organ Function Test =     461 / 463
Patient Related     =     101 / 113
Totals              = 1,294 / 9,081
```

The misclassification errors for organ function test and patient related are relatively higher. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just some quick things you can do to improve this:

- Look at performance metrics on a validation set, including the confusion matrix
- Perhaps try hyperparameter tuning to improve performance for your task (using `h2o.grid`:http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/grid-search.html)
- Consider using h2o.word2vec for feature generation (Docs: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-r/demos/rdemo.word2vec.craigslistjobtitles.R and Example: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-r/demos/rdemo.word2vec.craigslistjobtitles.R)

If you provide more details and a working example there is more that can be done to help you.